# Extracting the pixelwise proportion of classes of a finer raster in a coarser one

Tags: python, raster, gdal, overlay, vectorization

I have two rasters, one has a 1 km resolution. The other has a spatial resolution of 30 m. This latter pixelwise is a classification. I want to overlay the 1 km raster on the classification raster and extract for each 1 km pixel the distribution of classes corresponding to the 30 m classification.

[image]

The 30 m classification includes 7 classes so I would want this process to produce 7 new layers at 1 km. One for each class. Each pixel of 1 km will now have associated a corresponding % of the presence of each class present in the 30 m classification. If one made a table where each row is a pixel then one would have a table like the following:

[image]

One additional difficulty is that the rasters are quite big. I would really like to achieve this using python.

**EDIT:**

I have added subsets of my two datasets a [this](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q11zfia5fpmlj14/AAAa2f4h1YfHGNwfzCocWJCLa?dl=0) link (at 30m and 1000m resolutions respectively), in case anyone wants to propose a proof of concept; would be amazing.

Comment: Not a full solution but just an idea: Maybe you could generate a fishnet grid of 1km x 1km resolution, and then use rectangles generated as inputs into the zonal statistics (or zonal statistics as table) tool. you could then use those statistics to calculate the % that you need, and then convert the rectangles to a raster.

Comment: Can you post your data for me to work on? I think I have a solution, I want to test it on your data first though. I am thinking this would pretty simple in R but I can probably work it up in arcpy also... anyway, I look forward to trying to resolve this!

Comment: How can I post data? I think it's quite big. Is it allowed to link to dropbox or something? I don't have arcgis, would it be really hard to implement it in python as is? Sorry for being so picky.

Comment: I apologize, I was under the impression you were using arc, no that is no worries, no apology necessary... as far as what is allowed -- see this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15821/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-sharing-files-and-resources   a dropbox link would be fine

Comment: What do you mean by quite big ? If you haven't seen them, there is some useful [slides from C. Garrard](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides4.pdf) about handling raster in python with gdal.
I guess these slides suggest you can iterate over each pixel of the 1*1km layer, then use this "window' for defining a block of pixels to read on the 30*30m layer and compute the % of each value in this block (just a guess).
Anyway if you find the slides helpful, change the '4' to '5' and/or to '6' in the url for more slides about raster and python.

Comment: Your illustration shows a join of seven zonal summaries of the high-res raster, using the pixels of the low-res raster as zones. Equivalently--and perhaps even more efficiently--they can be obtained from seven "aggregate" operations.  Although that's seven calculations, they're routine and quick in a raster GIS.  Completing them would likely take less time than writing this question did :-). Do you have a GIS or do you really want to write the Python code from scratch?

Comment: I use QGIS generally, don't have access to a ArcGIS license. It would be nice to know how to do this in QGIS if it is as easy as you mention but since I will perform this many many times I am interested in the automation of the process.

Comment: @JEquihua you actually have 27 unique classes (not 7) between 1 and 31. You can make a 31-band analysis instead, which works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Step 1

Make bit rasters for each of the unique classes. This can be a 1-band rasters for each class, or a single raster with a band for each class (e.g. GeoTIFF). If using [GTiff](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html), you can use the creation option `NBITS=1` to conserve space. You may also want to consider twobit rasters to store [three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) where the third (e.g. 2) is NODATA, which would require `NBITS=2`.

For each band / class, the pixels will be 0 where that class does not exist, or 1 where that class exists.

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()

# Get data from raster with classifications
ds = gdal.Open('cropped_30m.tif')
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
class_ar = band.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
pj = ds.GetProjection()
ds = band = None  # close

# Define the raster values for each class, to relate to each band
class_ids = (np.arange(31) + 1).tolist()

# Make a new bit rasters
drv = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
ds = drv.Create('bit_raster.tif', class_ar.shape[1], class_ar.shape[0],
                len(class_ids), gdal.GDT_Byte,
                ['NBITS=1', 'COMPRESS=LZW', 'INTERLEAVE=BAND'])
ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)
ds.SetProjection(pj)
for bidx in range(ds.RasterCount):
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(bidx + 1)
    # create boolean
    selection = (class_ar == class_ids[bidx])
    band.WriteArray(selection.astype('B'))
ds = band = None  # save, close
```

E.g. for Red = Band 10, Green = Band 13 and Blue = Band 27, it can be visualised:

[image: 30m]

Black indicates it is another class / band.

## Step 2

Use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to get the *average* of 0 and 1 values from a coarser sample grid. This method requires GDAL >= 1.10.0. A really simply way to do this is to specify a target resolution on the command line, e.g. 1 km:

```
$ gdalwarp -ot Float32 -tr 1000 1000 -r average bit_raster.tif average_1km.tif
```

The result will have as many bands as classes, and each band will describe the fraction of that class for each pixel, between 0 and 1. If you prefer percent, then multiply it by 100 (e.g. see [gdal_calc.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html)).

There is also a Python interface to gdalwarp (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538634/327026)), which can use a template raster for shape and where NODATA should be used. For example:

```
# Open raster from step 1
src_ds = gdal.Open('bit_raster.tif')

# Open a template or copy array, for dimensions and NODATA mask
cpy_ds = gdal.Open('cropped_1000m.tif')
band = cpy_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
cpy_mask = (band.ReadAsArray() == band.GetNoDataValue())

# Result raster, with same resolution and position as the copy raster
dst_ds = drv.Create('average2_1km.tif', cpy_ds.RasterXSize, cpy_ds.RasterYSize,
                    len(class_ids), gdal.GDT_Float32, ['INTERLEAVE=BAND'])
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(cpy_ds.GetGeoTransform())
dst_ds.SetProjection(cpy_ds.GetProjection())

# Do the same as gdalwarp -r average; this might take a while to finish
gdal.ReprojectImage(src_ds, dst_ds, None, None, gdal.GRA_Average)

# Convert all fractions to percent, and apply the same NODATA mask from the copy raster
NODATA = -9999
for bidx in range(dst_ds.RasterCount):
    band = dst_ds.GetRasterBand(bidx + 1)
    ar = band.ReadAsArray() * 100.0
    ar[cpy_mask] = NODATA
    band.WriteArray(ar)
    band.SetNoDataValue(NODATA)

# Save and close all rasters
src_ds = cpy_ds = dst_ds = band = None
```

E.g. the same three bands (classes) can be visualised as RGB:

[image: 1km]

Or pull it into QGIS, and use the Identify features tool to inspect the fraction for each band/classification at a single location:

[image: QGIS]

These number add up to 100%, which is a good check.

Comment: It's running, ill let you know if it turned out fine, thank you. By the way gdal and numpy dtypes don't get along so well so I had to modify the code where you write the bands to disk: selection = (class_ar == class_ids[bidx]).astype("u1")
  band.WriteArray(selection)

Comment: It's going very very slow but getting there. One question, how does this process handle the projection, extent, etc of the output raster? What I'm worried about is how am I going to align the output raster to my original 1km raster? (30m and 1km are in have same projection).

Comment: @JEquihua updated to align to the 1km raster, and copy the NODATA locations, multiply the values to percent

Comment: @MikeT and JEquihua I have the exact same task in my hands described in this question thread. I have downloaded the files and ran the code suggested. It does indeed create 2 raster files with 31 bands, but all values in the rasters are zero, although the "ar" variable in the python environment seems to have the percent values. Any idea on what might be wrong?

Comment: Ah, this was done in Python 2, that's why! Just leaving it here for future reference.